# Can a form have more than one on submit?

Tags: reactjs

As mentioned above, can a form have more than one onsubmit?

For example

```
<form onSubmit={sendEMail, this.handleSubmit}>
```

Comment: Do you want more submit handler or do you wish to achieve two actions on button click?

Answer (score 0):

Define a function that takes the event argument, then calls both `sendEMail` and `this.handleSubmit` with it:

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {
  sendEMail(e);
  this.handleSubmit(e);
}}>
```